# Is there a naming convention for C language implementation only (private) constants?

Tags: c, naming

Let's say that I am writing a library named `my`, which has a module `myString`.

Publicly exposed functions and constants for `myString` are declared in `myString.h` with the following convention:

```
typedef struct myString myString;
extern const size_t MY_STRING_MAX_LEN;
myString *my_string_new();
```

Private implementation only functions and struct members are declared in `myString.c` with the following convention:

```
_grow_buffer(myString *this);
char *_buffer;
```

My question: Is there a similar convention for private, implementation only constants?

For example, `_CHUNK_SIZE` is what I initially wanted to go with. Then I read that the C language specification says not to use an underscore followed by an uppercase letter at the start of a name, as such names may be used in future versions of the language.

I like using the starting underscore convention, as it removes a lot of verbosity. I could use `MY_STRING_CHUNK_SIZE` or some variation, but that's not as pretty IMO.

Comment: Not exactly within the scope of your question but please note that many people [argue](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1923) that the use of all-upper-case identifiers should be limited to macros. I agree with those people.

Comment: @5gon12eder: Actually this is the only well-accepted naming convention.

Comment: Curious why do some identifies begin with "my" and others with `my_"?  IMO, it should be one of the other.

Answer (score 3):

In the C language, file scope identifiers with linkage, such as function and variable names, are made private to a translation unit by *internal* linkage. Internal linkage is indicated using the `static` storage class specifier:

```
static char *buffer;
static void  grow_buffer(my_string *str) { /* ... */ }
```

This does not solve all problems. In a large code base, there may be multiple identifiers such as `grow_buffer` and `buffer`. When you want to search for the definition of `buffer`, it is annoying to be given half a dozen possibilities.

For that reason, it's still not a bad idea to use some prefix convention on static identifiers, such as the same prefix that is used on the public functions.  That also saves you from having to rename identifiers if you decide to change their classification from static to external or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Well, How about `CHUNK_SIZE_`. This convention is quite prevailing in C++ since it does not confilict with the "reserved" `_XX` or `__XX`